# Are there any all in one packages like XAMPP for Django?

Tags: python, django

Like with XAMPP you can just install it and start developing because PHP/MySQL/Apache, etc. are all in there.

Is there anything like this for Django?

P.S. I meant just for developing on my local machine not for deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I've seen is [Bitnami's DjangoStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack). There is arguably little need for a comparable XAMPP stack to get started with Django development, as the only thing you need to get started with Django is Python 2.x. Most linux distros and OSX include Python 2.x. The easiest way to install Django is to use `easy_install` (preferably from [distribute](http://python-distribute.org/)) or [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/). It can't get much easier if you are happy using the built-in development server and SQLite:

`$ easy_install django`

If you *don't* have `easy_install` or `pip` available, or you don't know how to use them from a terminal...*learn*. You can use `pip` or `easy_install` to automatically install an incredible amount of packages/apps for Python OR Django. Don't miss out on that! I prefer `pip` for a number of reasons, which you can learn about better from their [documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/#introduction).

**This is probably all you need for local development.** Well [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) too, but I won't get into that.

I have also seen [InstantDjango](http://www.instantdjango.com/) which tries to be a one-click installer for Windows. Although Bitnami's DjangoStack has a native-installer for Windows, I'd imagine you'd be better off using a VM (Bitnami offers a VM image you can use and there is also another Django appliance available from [Turnkey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/django)). Or (even better) you could easily create your own Linux VM (with the distro of your choice, tools of your choice, etc).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is just starting developing your site with sqlite and the development server provided by django.

When you are ready to deploy, simply find a [django friendly hosting service](http://djangofriendly.com/hosts/) and upload your site.

Then u wouldn't need to worry about the trouble of installing apache and database.

Answer (score 1):

Django has built in server for that. You can run it with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

As for MySQL, it makes about no difference at all, if you used SQLite for develovepment.