# XAMPP-Like Stack for Django

Tags: python, django, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any all in one packages like XAMPP for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929696/are-there-any-all-in-one-packages-like-xampp-for-django)

Is there a web server solution stack for Python/Django like XAMPP is for PHP? Thanks!

Comment: Don't rule out ASP.NET as it can be run on an Apache server on Linux - http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Comment: But the ASP.NET I know is WebPages, which uses .NET Framework 4 - 4.5

Comment: Check out these links: http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility and http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support

Comment: Thank you for this! I thought WebPages can never run on other platforms aside Win. But I'm still looking for other web frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider one of the [BitNami Django Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) native installers:

> BitNami native installers automate the setup of a BitNami application
>   stack on Windows, Linux or Mac OS X. Each installer includes all of
>   the software necessary to run out of the box (the stack).

You can also choose between Django stack for VMWare and Django stack for Amazon Cloud. I never tried them but I don't see why they shouldn't work.